# How to stop photoswipe thumbnail click function while swiping parent swiper slide?

Tags: photoswipe, swiper.js

I am using photoswipe and swiper plugins for my website. I have fetched photoswipe gallery inside a swper-slide class which is working fine. The problem when I try to swipe the swiper slide the photoswipe thumbnail gets clicked on and brings out the overlayed gallery. I need to stop the photoswipe click function while I swipe the swiper slide.